# If I had time so much to do... vs If I managed so much to do

Tags: conditional-constructions

Are both sentences correct? Have they got the same meaning? Which one is better to use?

> I have a lot to do today. If I had time so much to do, we could go out.
>
> I have a lot to do today. If I managed so much to do, we could go out.

TIA

Comment: Neither is correct. Could you elaborate on what you mean in either sentence?

Comment: I try to say: "If I had enough time to do so much..." more shortly.

Comment: That still doesn't mean anything to me. Please explain what you're trying to say using ***more words***, not "more shortly". As a "whole sentence", please *(**IF** [some condition] **THEN** some consequence)*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Reinstate Monica, are you Wehage?

Comment: I don't understand that either. Just tell us what exactly is preventing the speaker in your example from going out.

Comment: This needs a complete rethink.. I can't even make a guess as to what is being communicated.

Comment: @Sergey, if you mean to say that the person's current tasks at hand must be completed before they can go out with the other person, this is one way to communicate that: "If I manage to do it all, we can go out." (This does _not_ express unlikelihood)

Comment: @Wehage, I must use 2nd conditional.

Comment: @Sergey "If I had time to do it all/to do all that, we could go out." Keep in mind that this is dependent on the prior sentence "I have a lot to do today," which you edited in later.